# Build SuperTuxKart on Mac OS X(failed to create symbolic link 'lib/libpng.pc': No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, c, macos, cmake, libpng

I'm trying to build a open source game called SuperTuxKart on Mac OS X 10.10, following the official instruction [here](http://supertuxkart.sourceforge.net/Building_and_packaging_on_OSX).

However, when I typed "cmake .. -DUSE_CPP2011=1" or "cmake .. -GXcode", I got error message:
`failed to create symbolic link 'lib/libpng.pc': No such file or directory
failed to create symbolic link 'lib/libpng-config': No such file or directory`
.

It seems the package has "lib/libpng/libpng.p" and "lib/libpng/libpng.pc" in "cmake_build" directory but not 'lib/libpng.pc' and 'lib/libpng-config'.

Is it the reason? Is the problem caused by the some bugs in the cmake script provided by the package or cause by that I didn't install libpng properly? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH 
    This is used when searching for libraries e.g. using the FIND_LIBRARY() command. If you have libraries in non-standard locations, it may be useful to set this variable to this directory (e.g. /sw/lib on Mac OS X). If you need several directories, separate them by the platform specific separators (e.g. ":" on UNIX)

cmake -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="your path" ...